# how to improve the drilling performance of d3 sunburst chart when there are too many paths? like dynamically show partial levels?

Tags: javascript, d3.js, sunburst-diagram

I'm new to d3 and now trying to render a sunburst chart with a really big set of data. But I find out that with the number of paths goes up, the drilling of chart becomes dull, like stops for one sec and then drills.

Is there any way to improve this? I'm thinking to display a limited number of levels but how to make showing levels dynamically change when the center changes?

```
function click(d) {
    var duration = config.animationDuration || config.animationDuration === 0 ? config.animationDuration : 1000;
    path.transition()
        .duration(duration)
        .attrTween("d", arcTween(d))

    path.attr("display", function(d){
        if(d.depth>config.drillDownPath.length + data.levelLimit-1) return "none";
    });    }
```

In the code above, I tracked the chart drilldown path to decide if a path is shown or not. But this didn't solve the question because the the path still exists in the DOM.

Can anyone help me with this? Thanks!

Comment: Could you post a complete example, preferably on jsfiddle or something like that please? It's impossible to say what exactly is going on without that -- it could be performance issues with computing the layout, performance issues with the rendering, or something with the animations.

Comment: Hi Lars, thanks for reply. I wrote the viz with angular so there are controller-directive-service layers, it's hard to show all the code. I paste my main d3 code here https://jsfiddle.net/0omm0ar1/1/.                                        I'm actually not sure about the cause for bad performance. Maybe you are right, it's not because of large dataset. However, when my dataset is not that big, all the rendering and animation work pretty good.

Comment: Thanks, but your jsfiddle doesn't work. It would also depend on what kind of big your data set is -- many levels or the number of things at a level?

Comment: I write the sunburst a class as service within angualr framework so a lot of parameters and communication between directive and chart services are hard to show in jsfiddle. My dataset could be as big as more than 10 levels and also quite a lot of arcs on one level. Do you have any suggestion for improve performance for sunburst rendering large dataset? Is there any problem with my arcTween function? Thanks so much for the help.

Comment: As I've said, really hard to tell without seeing a working example.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is a bit late, but I might try [this example](http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/5944371) for displaying a large hierarchical dataset allowing for the user to drill down to any level.

By only rendering and transitioning 2-3 levels of arcs at a time, your transitions will probably lag less and the chart would probably be more readable. However, as mentioned by Lars, it's really hard to give you a concrete demo without seeing more code...